# React createPortal with getelementbyid fails every second time I refresh in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, bpmn.io, redwoodjs, bpmn-js

This code works perfectly every second refresh in Chrome. The other time it complains about the target not being a dom node. Any suggestions as to why it consistently fail on every second refresh?

This is a Redwood project using BPMN-JS and it is the createPortal to "asidecontent" that is the culprit

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import BpmnModeler from 'bpmn-js/lib/Modeler'
import { BpmnPropertiesPanelModule } from 'bpmn-js-properties-panel'
import { BpmnPropertiesProviderModule } from 'bpmn-js-properties-panel'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

import { Head } from '@redwoodjs/web'
interface BpmnEditorProps {
  filePath: string
}

const BpmnTest: React.FC<BpmnEditorProps> = ({ filePath }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const modelerRef = useRef<BpmnModeler | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current
    if (!container) return

    // Check if modeler is already mounted and unmount it if required
    if (modelerRef.current) {
      modelerRef.current.destroy()
      modelerRef.current = null
    }

    // Create a new instance of the modeler
    const modeler = new BpmnModeler({
      container,
      propertiesPanel: {
        parent: '#bpmn-properties-panel',
      },
      additionalModules: [
        BpmnPropertiesPanelModule,
        BpmnPropertiesProviderModule,
      ],
    })

    modelerRef.current = modeler

    const loadBpmnDiagram = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(filePath)
        const xml = await response.text()

        modeler.importXML(xml, (err: any) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error rendering BPMN diagram:', err)
          } else {
            console.log('BPMN diagram rendered successfully.')

            // Open properties panel initially
            const canvas = modeler.get('canvas')
            canvas.zoom('fit-viewport')
          }
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading BPMN diagram:', error)
      }
    }

    loadBpmnDiagram()

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      if (modelerRef.current) {
        modelerRef.current.destroy()
        modelerRef.current = null
      }
    }
  }, [filePath])

  const sidebarcontent = document.getElementById('asidecontent')
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bpmn-js.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/diagram-js.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bpmn-embedded.css" />
      </Head>
      <div ref={containerRef} style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
      {sidebarcontent !== null &&
        createPortal(
          <div id="bpmn-properties-panel" style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
          sidebarcontent
        )}
    </>
  )
}

export default BpmnTest
```

I have tried several methods to verify that the div with asidecontent is found before doing the create portal call but they all fail or are inconsequential - including the one in the example code.